# Смена иконки через каждых 6 часов через JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3

Здравствуйте формучане!
Помогите реализовать смену иконки раз 6 часов через js скрипт.

**Код HTML**

```
<h4 class="f-w-600"><span id="greeting">Good Morning</span></h4>
```

В этом HTML коде мы получаем от **id="greeting"** время суток от **js скрипта**. Через каждых 6 часов идет смена приветствия: **Доброй ночи, Добрые утро, Добрый день, Добрый вечер**

**Код JS**

```
    var today = new Date()
var curHr = today.getHours()

if (curHr >= 0 && curHr < 4) {
    document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = 'Доброй ночи';
} else if (curHr >= 4 && curHr < 12) {
    document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = 'Доброе утро';
} else if (curHr >= 12 && curHr < 16) {
    document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = 'Добрый день';
} else {
    document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = 'Добрый вечер';
}
```

В **JS** коде идет сама смена времени и вместе с ним идет смена слов например: **'Доброй ночи'** как добавить так чтобы можно было сменить и иконку в месте со словом?

Пробивал вот: `document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = 'Доброй ночи <span class="right-circle setting-bg-primary">';` так не получилось.

Comment: Может вы забыли закрыть элемент `<span>`? `'Доброй ночи <span class="right-circle setting-bg-primary"></span>';`

Comment: @oliver-patterson: Спасибо решил свой вопрос другим способом. Спасибо за отзыв. Проблема была не в закрывающем теге **</span>**

Comment: Может тогда напишите, в чем была проблема? Может кто-то столкнется с этим же (хотя сомневаюсь).

Answer (score 3):

```js
var today = new Date()
var curHr = today.getHours()
var icon = document.createElement('span');
var greeting = document.getElementById("greeting");

if (curHr >= 0 && curHr < 4) {
    greeting.innerHTML = 'Доброй ночи';
    icon.classList.add('fa','fa-star')
} else if (curHr >= 4 && curHr < 12) {
    greeting.innerHTML = 'Доброе утро';
    icon.classList.add('fa','fa-sun-o')
} else if (curHr >= 12 && curHr < 16) {
    greeting.innerHTML = "Добрый день ";
    icon.classList.add('fa','fa-sun-o')
} else {
    greeting.innerHTML = 'Добрый вечер';
    icon.classList.add('fa','fa-moon-o')
}
greeting.append(icon);
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h4 class="f-w-600"><span id="greeting">Good Morning</span></h4>
```

Answer (score 2):

твой проект можно сделать вот так:
HTML:

```
    <i class="fa fa-spinner" id="icon"></i>
```

JavaScript:

```
    let icon1 = "fa fa-history";
    let icon2 = "fa fa-android";
    let icon3 = "fa fa-file";
    setInterval(function () {
      setTimeout(function () {
        document.querySelector("#icon"). className = icon1;
      }, 21600000);
      setTimeout(function () {
        document.querySelector("#icon"). className = icon2;
      }, 43200000);
      document.querySelector("#icon"). className = icon3;
      }, 64800000);
    }, 21600000);
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: У вас невалидный код, который пытается менять иконку через промежутки времени, а не в зависимости от текущего времени, как нужно ТС